# Is per diem taxable?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Earlier this year, my employer reimbursed $500 that I paid out of my own pocket for travel expenses as per diem. I was not charged any tax on that, so I was wondering whether it would be taxable at the end of the year and at what rate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per-diem is not taxable, if all the conditions are met. Conditions include:

1. Expense report from the employee, which includes the dates, business purpose and receipts for lodging (if meal only per diem is provided).
2. Per diem is less or equal to the Federal per-diem rate.
3. Report submitted within reasonable period (usually within 60 days of the trip)

You can find this and more in this [IRS FAQ document re the per-diem](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-regs/perdiemfaq&a.prn.pdf).